# I can't get the line-height property to change anything

Tags: css

I feel like everything is written correctly here, but changing the line-height does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erwuI.png)

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub5QR.png)

Comment: May be the post help you about your issue https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/line-height-not-working/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the inner `h2` element's `line-height` like

```
div#greet > h1{
  line-height:2em;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I didn't realize that you could use selectors in that way. It is really helpful. Thank you :)